# How to mount HDFS on Cloudera?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, mount, nfs

I am working on a cluster running Cloudera 5.3, and I've followed all the instructions to create an NFS gateway and it's running fine. My problem is that I still can't see the HDFS directories as part of the Linux file system (this is RHEL 6). I'm not a UNIX admin so I have no experience mounting directories, and the documentation I'm finding online isn't helping with this specific problem. I've tried the simple

```
mount /
```

On the machine that is the NFS gateway, but that didn't work. When I tried from another cluster machine to mount using

```
mount <myNFSgateway>:/ /
```

I couldn't see any of the files on the gateway server nor in HDFS (though I can easily see the files using `hdfs dfs -ls`).

How do I actually mount HDFS as a directory now that NFS is set up?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command for checking available mount points

```
showmount -e <nfs_server_ip_address>
```

You should see output similar to the following:

```
Exports list on <nfs_server_ip_address>: 
/ (everyone)
```

Mounting HDFS on an NFS Client
To import the HDFS file system on an NFS client, use a mount command such as the following on the client:

```
 mount -t  nfs  -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock <nfs_server_hostname>:/ /hdfs_nfs_mount
```

(Before mounting make sure the nfs related libraries are installed. if not, install the libraries using the command `sudo yum install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib`)

Comment: I tried that version of the mount command as well (got it from the Apache site), but it still didn't work. It's not recognizing the directory in hdfs, e.g. "/my/hdfs/dir does not exist" when I try to mount it.

Comment: You can mount only / HDFS directory, Did you  install the dependent packages mentioned in the answer ?

Comment: I did install those packages. When I tried to mount /, it still didn't work. I can ask Cloudera about it, I was just hoping there might be something simple I was missing.

Comment: Did you start the nfs gateway service ?

Comment: I did start the gateway service successfully

Comment: Cool !!. Post the issue, you were facing and the fix as a separate answer.